# Returning Errors without a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, error-handling

I need to know the number of rows in a certain table.  If it is under 250 rows I need to return an error to the sql job forcing it to quit.  The problem is it's not a stored procedure.  It's sql code is running straight from the job step as a Transact-SQL script.  Is this possible to return anything, or is there a better way to do this?

This is what I have:
select case when (select cnt = count([col]) from db.dbo.table) < 250 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the RAISERROR command.

```
IF (SELECT COUNT([col] FROM db.dbo.table) < 250
    RAISERROR('My error message', 15, 1)
```

The severity level 15 is a level that will indicate to the job that the command failed.

Look here for more about the [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) command.

Comment: yep, you can have multiline and complex statements in a tsql job step